# How to raiserror in SQL Server 2016 compatible with SQL Server 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, error-handling, sql-server-2016

I wrote a script which check referencing objects on SQL Server versions from 2008 to 2016.

In SQL Server 2008, `RaiseError` works fine, but in SQL Server 2016, when I use `TRY-CATCH`, I don't see any errors in messages even they occur.

How to do it, to work also on 2016 version and be compatible up to the SQL Server 2008 version?

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO @refTable
        SELECT
            @nestLevel,
            @referencingEntityFullName AS referencing_object_name,
            OBJECT_ID(@referencingEntityFullName) AS referencing_object_id,
            r.referencing_minor_id, --if > 0 then computed column
            r.referenced_server_name,
            r.referenced_database_name,
            r.referenced_schema_name,
            r.referenced_entity_name,
            r.referenced_minor_name,
            r.is_caller_dependent, --warning on these!
            r.is_ambiguous--,
            --r.is_selected,
            --r.is_updated,
            --r.is_select_all,
            --r.is_insert_all,
            --r.is_all_columns_found
        FROM
            sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(@referencingEntityFullName, 'OBJECT') r
        WHERE
            r.referenced_entity_name = @currentReferencedEntityName
            AND (@filterColumns = 0 OR 
                    r.referenced_minor_name IN (SELECT ColumnName 
                                                FROM @piiTablesAndColumns ptac 
                                                WHERE ptac.TableName = @currentReferencedEntityFullName)
                 OR r.referenced_minor_name IS NULL --for SELECT *; check if it really works this way
                )
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        print('catched!' + @referencingEntityFullName + CAST(OBJECT_ID(@referencingEntityFullName) AS NVARCHAR(1000)))

        INSERT INTO @refTable (referencing_object_name, referencing_object_id, referenced_entity_name) 
        VALUES (@referencingEntityFullName, OBJECT_ID(@referencingEntityFullName), (SELECT top 1 referenced_entity_name FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies WHERE referencing_id=OBJECT_ID(@referencingEntityFullName) and referenced_entity_name in (select replace(TableName,'dbo.','') from @piiTablesAndColumnsTmp)))
        RAISERROR('error',255,255)
    END CATCH
```

Comment: Are you migrating from SQL Server 2008 to 2016 (I hope so as 2008 has only 7 days left of support). If so, I'd suggest looking at [`THROW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: No, I need script which works 2008 and 2016

Comment: I would suggest you look at upgrade paths, based on my above comment. On a different note, when i run `RAISERROR('error',255,255)` (on SQL Server 2017, as I don't have access to a 2016 instance) I get the error `Error severity levels greater than 18 can only be specified by members of the sysadmin role, using the WITH LOG option.` Is the above being run as a `sysadmin`? if not, there's your problem (not that you should be using the `sysadmin` role here.

Comment: @Peter_K, how are you "catching" the error in SQL 2008: TRY ... CATCH or IF @@ERROR? If the latter you need to, after your RAISERROR, inject a RETURN statement. For more about error handling, (and explanation about the RETURN statement), see my blog post: https://nielsberglund.com/2016/12/31/sql-server-error-handling-gotchas/